# How does quantum contextuality relate to mutually commuting observables?

Tags: contextuality, nonclassicality

I am trying to get a better understanding of what is the idea behind quantum contextuality. Quoting from the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_contextuality) (emphasis mine):

> Quantum contextuality is a foundational concept in quantum mechanics stating that the outcome one observes in a measurement is dependent upon what other measurements one is trying to make. ***More formally, the measurement result of a quantum observable is dependent upon which other commuting observables are within the same measurement set***.

I am a bit confused by the phrasing here. If I have two commuting observables, $[A,B]=0$, that means that they do not interfere with one another, or, quoting from the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables), that "*the measurement of one observable has no effect on the result of measuring another observable in the set*".

Is this just bad phrasing (or a typo) on Wikipedia's side, or am I missing something?

Comment: **Related**: [Marginal and joint probability in quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346806/marginal-and-joint-probability-in-quantum-mechanics)

Comment: @SanchayanDutta ah, that makes sense. So they mean that one is considering a set of observables $\{A_k\}_k$, some of which can be commuting, but which is not a set of mutually commuting observables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this just bad phrasing (or a typo) on Wikipedia's side, or am I missing something?

It does sound like bad phrasing. The idea here is that our set of observables is not necessarily mutually (pairwise) commuting. If you have three observables $A$, $B$ and $C$, and $[A,B]=0$ and $[B,C]=0$, then you're right that the measurement of $A$ will have no effect on $B$ and the measurement of $B$ will have no effect on the measurement of $C$. But the measurement statistics of $B$ will still be context-dependent if you have a two observable set i.e. it'll depend on whether you have $A$ or $C$ in your set.

Now if you have all three, then there's some uncertainty in the joint measurement statistics. In other words, given well-defined marginal distributions $P(a,b|A,B)$ and $P(b,c|B,C)$, you cannot have a well-defined joint probability distribution $P(a,b,c|A,B,C)$ in this case (although interestingly, the uncertainty can be lower bounded in many cases).

There are some nice lectures on this topic:

- [Lecture on Quantum Contextuality by Dr. Pawel Kurzynski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZdmv6HC5OM)
- [Algorithmic Approach to Quantum Contextuality by Prof. Dagomir Kaszlikowski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT9YGrsMy1c)
- [Quantum Contextuality and Quantum Cryptography by Prof. Arvind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rjv2Z9tSodM)

Comment: thanks. I also just found [this other related post on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7280/58382) which contains some useful references.

Comment: @glS Nice. BTW there's a whole bunch of interesting inequalities related to this contextuality stuff (which I don't know much about) cf. KCBS inequality; will expand on this answer once I learn more.